# How to prove this property related to modular law for linear subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space, and let $A,B,M,N$ be linear subspaces of $V$ such that $A\cap B = M\cap N$. Prove that $A = (A+(B\cap M))\cap (A+(B\cap N)).$

**Proof**$\,$ (Incomplete)

$(\subseteq)$ is immediate.

Let $x\in A+(B\cap N)$. Then there exist $y,y\in A$, $z\in B\cap N$ and $z^\prime\in B\cap N$ such that $x = y+z = y^\prime+z^\prime$. If I can show that $z = z^\prime$ the the proof is complete, but I don't see how to justify $z = z^\prime$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x\in (A+(B\cap M))\cap (A+(B\cap N))$. Then there exists $a,a'\in A$, $z\in B\cap M$ and $z'\in B\cap N$ such that
$$x=a+z=a'+z'.$$
Thus $a-a'=z'-z\in A\cap B.$
So by assumptions, $a-a'=z'-z\in M\cap N$.
Thus, $z'=a-a'+z\in M$. Since $z'\in N$, one has $z'\in M\cap N=A\cap B$, so that $z'\in A$ and $x=a'+z'\in A$.